# How Guice behaves differently as injection types change

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Say we have the following code:

```
public interface Rock {
    // Minerals are a concrete class; omitted for brevity
    public Minerals getMinerals();
}

public class Granite implements Rock {
    // @Inject #1 - field
    private Minerals minerals;

    // @Inject #2 - constructor
    public Granite(Minerals mins) {
        super();
        setMinerals(mins);
    }

    public Minerals getMinerals() {
        return minerals;
    }

    // @Inject #3 - setter
    public void setMinerals(Minerals mins) {
        minerals = mins
    }
}

public class RockModule extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure(Binder guiceBinder) {
        Minerals m = new Minerals(true, 3, MineralEnum.Sedimentary);

        guiceBinder.bind(Minerals.class).toInstance(m);
        guiceBinder.bind(Rock.class).to(Granite.class);
    }
}

public class TestInjections {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RockModule mod = new RockModule();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(mod);

        Granite gran = injector.getInstance(Granite.class);
    }
}
```

I have commented out the 3 `@Inject` annotations as they are the variables here - I'm wondering how Guice will behave in all 3 cases (field-, constructor- or setter-level injections).

- Will `Granite` instances **always** be injected with the `Minerals` instance configured in the module? How does the injection type (each of the 3) affect the `Granite` instances returned by the injector - or are they all the same?
- What if I never explicitly bound `Minerals` in the module at all **and** `Minerals` doesn't have a public no-arg constructor defined? For all three injection scenarios, how does Guice instantiate a `Minerals` instance to be returned for the requested `Granite` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Minerals` will always be injected into the `Granite`, whichever injection technique you choose, but some injections are "cleaner" than others -- for example, option 1 gives you less control over how the injection is done, and option 3 means your class can't be immutable.
2. If `Minerals` isn't bound, lacks a public no-argument constructor, and lacks an `@Inject` constructor, then Guice throws an exception, unless you use `@Inject(optional = true)`.

Comment: How does the field-level injection limit me/give me less control (example)? Also what if I only annotate the setter with `@Inject`, then use the injector to create a `Granite` instance? How would Guice know to map the `Minerals` instance (defined in the module) to this `Granite` instance if the setter is never invoked?

Comment: 1. What if you didn't want to use the injected object directly as a field, but you wanted to wrap it or pass it to a method or to another field?  Only constructor and setter injection can do that.  2. Guice scans your class for `@Inject` setter methods when it's obtaining that object, and calls them, so even though you don't see the invocation, the setter does get invoked.

Comment: So it sounds like field-level injection is loosely regarded as "Evil with a few exceptions", and setter-level injection limits your ability to declare properties that are `final` (immutable). It sounds like constructor-level injection is the preferred way to go, at least for Guice newbies. Are these fair statements? And thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: That is absolutely correct.  Aside from a few unusual cases -- specifically, optional injection can't be done with constructors -- constructor injection is generally most compatible with best practices.